# Default value is taken as (empty) for a string in swagger even though i have given a default value

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to integrate swagger with my project.

I have given the dependencies in pom, copied the dist folder from swagger into my workspace.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oss-jfrog-artifactory</id>
        <name>oss-jfrog-artifactory-releases</name>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local</url>
    </repository>
</repositories> 

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ajar</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-spring-mvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I haven't created the swagger config class but added these in application context.

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean name="springSwaggerConfig" class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig" />

<bean id="swaggerSpringMvcPlugin" class="com.mangofactory.swagger.plugin.SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin">
    <constructor-arg ref="springSwaggerConfig"></constructor-arg> 
</bean>
```

My API accepts a path variable and gives me the response. This is the sample API

```
@ApiOperation(value="This is the test API")
    @RequestMapping(value = "sayHello/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String testAPI(@ApiParam(defaultValue="xyz", required=true) @PathVariable String userName){
        return "Hello" + userName; 
    }
```

Even though i have given a default value it is not taking the value, instead it is taking the value as (empty).

When trying to check the request and response on swagger, there is not text box against the value nor the "Try it out" button.

Can you please let me know what needs to be done to fix the issue.!

Comment: The first step would be to use the latest version of the library which is currently 0.9.5. If that doesn't work, then it's probably a bug. You won't get any workaround here, you just need to open an issue on the project's repository.

Comment: Just a side note. When you add a `defaultValue`, you are making that parameter as non-`required`, so your `required` flag isn't doing much there...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a default value for a *PathVariable* in Spring MVC, 'cause than there would be no way to distinguish between the request with empty path variable and the one holding the default value, so the mappings wouldn't match.

For what concerns the missing input field, you should set the following attributes to your annoatation

```
@ApiParam(required=true, paramType = "path") @PathVariable String userName
```

Comment: Ok.. But how can i enter the value for path variable in swagger-ui if i dont get a text box and "Try it out" button on ui.  Attached screen shot will tell you how the ui is being displayed for me.

Comment: perhaps I've confused you with my answer, edited it now

Comment: I wanted to try out the API for different values of userName. For that i need to give different values for the path variable. But i was not able to give that in the UI even after i removed the default value for api param.

Comment: Please refer the screenshot attached. I am not able to pass the path variable. Its value is being shown as (empty)

Comment: I've edited again adding the paramType="path" its what you were missing